# SQL LEFT JOIN not returning null values

Tags: postgresql

It feels like it should be simple but I'm missing some knowledge on joins.

Suppose I have two tables:

```
bi_view_in_invoices            payments 
id     due_date                id      payment_system_paid_date
1      2020-01-15              1       2020-01-16
2      2020-02-13              2       2020-01-10
3      2020-03-01              2       2020-02-19
4      2020-03-02              3       2020-02-11
                               3       2020-03-03
                               4       2020-02-11
```

I want to join these two tables on id: to return due_date from Table1 and only return payment_system_paid_date from Table2 if it is between one day before due_date and three days after. Else it should return null.
It should look like that:

```
Result:                
id     due_date      payment_system_paid_date
1      2020-01-15    2020-01-16
2      2020-02-13    null  
3      2020-03-01    2020-03-03        
4      2020-03-02    null
```

I tried this SQL:

```
select bvii.id, bvii.due_date, h1.pd, *
from bi_view_in_invoices bvii 
left join payments p 
    on bvii.id = p.id
inner join (
    select bvii.number, min(p.payment_system_paid_date) as pd
    from bi_view_in_invoices bvii 
    left join payments p 
    on bvii.id = p.id
    where p.payment_system_paid_date >= (bvii.due_date - 1)
    and p.payment_system_paid_date <= (bvii.due_date + 3)
    group by bvii.number
) h1
    on bvii.number = h1.number 
    and p.payment_system_paid_date = h1.pd
```

It returns me only these ids which have date and does not return null values.
My result looks like this:

```
id     due_date      payment_system_paid_date
1      2020-01-15    2020-01-16
3      2020-03-01    2020-03-03
```

Could you advise me what am I doing wrong?

I have also tried to add:

*or p.payment_system_paid_date is not null and h1.pd is null*

but seems like it does not work either.

Thanks!

Comment: Should be `... left join payments p on (bvii.id = p.id and p.payment_system_paid_date >= (bvii.due_date - 1) and p.payment_system_paid_date <= (bvii.due_date + 3)) group by bvii.number ...`

Comment: it seems to be working! just one more issue: I actually need to use a few more columns from my tables and I cannot use group by as then all the columns in select must be used in an aggregate function. 
Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: It is yet another, different question.

Answer (score 0):

```
with t1(x,y) as (values(1,10),(2,20)), t2(x,y) as (values(1,12),(2,18))
select *
from t1 left join t2 on (t1.x = t2.x)
where t1.y < t2.y;

┌───┬────┬───┬────┐
│ x │ y  │ x │ y  │
├───┼────┼───┼────┤
│ 1 │ 10 │ 1 │ 12 │
└───┴────┴───┴────┘

with t1(x,y) as (values(1,10),(2,20)), t2(x,y) as (values(1,12),(2,18))
select *
from t1 left join t2 on (t1.x = t2.x and t1.y < t2.y);

┌───┬────┬──────┬──────┐
│ x │ y  │  x   │  y   │
├───┼────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 1 │ 10 │    1 │   12 │
│ 2 │ 20 │ ░░░░ │ ░░░░ │
└───┴────┴──────┴──────┘
```

`where` condition here downgrades `left join` to `inner join` implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens when second table, in this case payments table, does not contain any matching record. In our team, we have solved this problem using sub count query like below:

```
select bvii.id, bvii.due_date, h1.pd, *
from bi_view_in_invoices bvii 
left join payments p 
    on bvii.id = p.id
inner join (
    select bvii.number, min(p.payment_system_paid_date) as pd
    from bi_view_in_invoices bvii 
    left join payments p 
    on bvii.id = p.id
    where
((select count(*) from payment where id=p.id)=0 or (select count(*) from payment where id=p.id)>0) and
p.payment_system_paid_date >= (bvii.due_date - 1)
    and p.payment_system_paid_date <= (bvii.due_date + 3)
    group by bvii.number
) h1
    on bvii.number = h1.number 
    and p.payment_system_paid_date = h1.pd
```

pay attention to the part `((select count(*) from payment where id=p.id)=0 or (select count(*) from payment where id=p.id)>0)`

and as convention, avoid null values with `coalesce()` function.